# PouchDB, how to add a new attachment in a doc which already has a attachment?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I hava a doc with some attachments, now i want to add a new attachment, how to do it ?
      I use db.put() to save my doc, however at last only the new attachment in it, the old attachments are lost, my update doc code is as following:

```
    function addNewDoc() {
    var blob30k = base64toBlob(imgSource30k, 'image/png', 1024);
    db.get('my0112doc', function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        db.put({
            _id: 'my0112doc',
            _rev: doc._rev,
            _attachments: {
                'random89.png': {
                    content_type: 'image/png',
                    data: blob30k
                },
            }
        }, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            db.allDocs({
                include_docs: true,
                attachments: true,
                descending: true
            }, function(err, doc) {
                console.log(doc.rows);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

this is my first time to save attachment in my doc, when i add a new one , the attachment 'myattachment.png' is lost.

```
    function saveImage(imgSource30M) {
    var t1 = new Date();
    var blob = base64toBlob(imgSource30M, 'image/png', 1024);
    db.put({
        _id: 'my0112doc',
        _attachments: {
            'myattachment.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            }
        }
    }, (err, doc) => {
        var t2 = new Date();
        console.log("save in pouchdb timeoff:", t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried pouchdb's [putAttachment](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#save_attachment) instead of `put`?

Comment: i tried  putAttachment() and it works ! i think this logic is strange， the put() can't work,but putAttachment can. however thanks Kevin.